# Can't drop table after creating table with wrong engine

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to drop a table containing several hundred thousand column-based records. Normally when creating the database I use a column-based engine (infinidb) but in this case I forgot to include the ENGINE statement. So the database is pretty much unusable for my needs. Now I have a database full of tables that are taking forever to drop (it's been twenty minutes and nothing has happened). I tried the ALTER TABLE table ENGINE=INFINIDB command but again, it's taking forever (see above re: twenty minutes).

Is there another way to get rid of this database? E.g. manually going into the /mysql/ directory and deleting the database? I guess I could just rename it and leave it, but I'd rather get rid of it entirely so it's not taking up space.

Comment: If you're about to trash the whole database why not wipe the directory and do a fresh `mysql_install_db`?

Comment: You mean the whole /mysql/ directory? Because a) there's fifteen other databases in there, and b) unfortunately, this is at my workplace, it's not my own project, so I can't just wipe everything and start from scratch.

Comment: `DROP DATABASE`, then reload.